# web form insert and trigger before insert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a oracle table called:

```
create table InsertHere(
    generate_id varchar2(10),
    name varchar2(100)
);
```

I have to insert data in this table from a web from. In the web form there are two 
elements:

> type and name

. I have to generate 'generate_id' from the type user has selected.

> Task :

Before insert into the InsertHere table i have to generate the **generate_id**. Then i have to insert
'generate_id' and 'name' into the InsertHere table. BUT THE GENERATION OF ID MUST BE DONE INSIDE THE
DATABASE(may be with a procedure).

Question:

How this thing can be done effectively?

I need suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends what you mean by "generating ID".  The ID is I presume a primary key, so its value must be unique regardless of TYPE.  So what rules do you want to apply to its generation?

Here is an indicative approach.  This uses a sequence to get a value and prepends a character, depending on `type`.

```
SQL> create or replace function generator
  2      (p_type varchar2
  3       , p_name in inserthere.name%type)
  4      return inserthere.generate_id%type
  5  is
  6      c char(1);
  7      return_value inserthere.generate_id%type;
  8  begin
  9      case p_type
 10          when 'EXTREME' then
 11              c := 'X';
 12          when 'REGULAR' then
 13              c := 'R';
 14          when 'JUMBO' then
 15              c := 'J';
 16          else
 17              c := 'P';
 18      end case;
 19
 20      insert into inserthere
 21          ( generate_id,
 22          name)
 23      values
 24          (c || lpad(trim(to_char(my_seq.nextval)), 9, '0')
 25           , p_name )
 26      returning generate_id into return_value;
 27
 28      return return_value;
 29  end;
 30  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

here it is in action

```
SQL> var n varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :n := generator ('EXTREME', 'ABC')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print n

N
--------------------------------
X000000001

SQL> exec :n := generator ('WHATEVER', 'SOMETHING')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print n

N
--------------------------------
P000000002

SQL>
```

You can vary the precise implementation, depending on how you want to call it.  As is often the case, details matter and more information will tend to result in a more relevant answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It would help me a lot. But i was thinking of using trigger instead. Because i have to do two things: first i have to generate the id before insert into the table. second i have to update the another table after inserting into the InsertHere table. But the problem is how can i pass parameter to trigger... ? or is there is another way?